# Angular How to call api in autocomplete field

Tags: autocomplete

Angular material how to call api in autocomplete field - Adding a custom filter. I have search forms with multiple mat autocomplete fields. I would like the user to be able to submit the search using the enter key. However, when the enter key is pressed after making a selection in any mat autocomplete field.

```
`<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      @for (option of filteredOptions | async; track option) {
        <mat-option [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
      }
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form> 
`
```